# Best datatype for a postgreSQL database in this situation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am kinda new to database design. Current design was working perfect until I found an issue.

Is a financial APP that recieve a lot of data.

There are mainly 2 data types:

Auto calculated where precision will be between 0% and 100% with 2 decimals, in few cases can be little more than 100%, so I set Numeric(6,2)

The other situation is raw data to calculate all those metrics. With big stocks I was ok with smallint/integer, because numbers are big and can be always integers (numbers like 257637, 188143) taking into account I save them in Millions. Problem is that, since I use millions unit, I realised that when I storage some small stocks those values can go as low as 0.10, so what should I do in this situation, go to Numeric(10,2) or so in all columns? Or there is another better way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen stock prices as low as a tenth of a basis point: `0.000010`. For a real-word app I would consider at least 6 decimal places.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: In this case Is a radar of stocks I personally choose, price is not a problem, will always be high since I dont do penny stocks. My problems are more with normal stuff as revenue, operating cash flow, net income, equity.... And yeah, my fault about fields :D language barrier.